# spring-data-jpa not working with java 8 LocalTime

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The query derivation mechanism of Spring Data repository (version 1.8) is not working properly with Java 8 LocalTime. Can someone tell me if I am doing wrong or is it a bug?

I store the starting time at 10:00 am

```
LocalTime startingTime = LocalTime.of(10,0); 
myEntity.setHorai(startingTime);
myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
```

Then I ask for all entities which starting time is greater than 08:00 am:

```
LocalTime zeroEight = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
List<MyEntity> ents = myEntityRepository.findByStartingTimeAfter(zeroEight);
```

I can see that Hibernate (I'm using Hibernate version 4.3.7.Final) executes this:

```
Hibernate: select <all fields> from MyEntity m_ where m_.startingTime>?
TRACE 2015-03-27 12:08:51,283 o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - [08:00]
```

So the List should contain 1 element, but it has 0 elements.
If instead of `findByStartingTimeAfter` I use `findByStartingTimeBefore` it returns 1 element, but I'm not sure if it is because I am misunderstanding the Before and After way of working. I've tried with `findByStartingTimeGreaterThan` but fails in the same way.

Maybe the query derivation mechanism doesn't work with Java 8 LocalTime?

Maybe be the problem on Hibernate, that is not comparing properly VARBINARY data (I can see the LocalTime is stored as BLOB but it is properly stored and retrieved as LocalTime)?

I'm using postgres 9.2 but I don't think the problem is on postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the question. Hibernate doesn't support java.time classes yet (it will in version 5.0). So it treats a LocalTime as a Serializable instance, and simply stores the serialized LocalTime instance as a byte array in a varbinary column. The `>` operator thus doesn't make much sense on this type of column, and won't compare LocalTime values chronologically.

You could define your own custom Hibernate type, or use [jadira](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) (which defines this custom type for you), to store the LocalTime value in an appropriate column type.

Comment: I'll wait for Hibernate 5. Thank you.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. Spring Data JPA 1.8 ships JPA 2.1 converters that allow you to persist these types out of the box on currently available persistence providers. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Without further mapping information Hibernate will treat JDK 8 dates as BLOBs and thus can't apply any comparison operations to those fields anymore.

One solution to this is to use the [Jadira User Types library](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) to customize the way those types are mapped to the database.

If you're only dealing with non-time-zoned types (e.g. `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`) the easiest way is to use the JPA 2.1 converters shipped with Spring Data JPA 1.8. Simply make sure `Jsr310JpaConverters` is the list of persistent classes (either through scanning the corresponding package or manually listing that class in your `persistence.xml`) and these JDK 8 specific date/time types are mapped to a `Date` transparently so that any persistence provider can persist them right away. Find more information on that in the [blog post announcing new features in the Spring Data Fowler release train](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler#jsr-310-and-threeten-backport-support).